# Фильтрация товаров yii2

Tags: php, yii2

на главной странице есть категории товаров.
(категория 1, категория 2, категория 3, категория 4)

реализована обычная модель + search модель + вью(внутри listView).

как с главной страницы передать инфу о категории в модель, чтобы на новой странице происходила сразу же фильтрация?

Код контроллера:

```php
/**
     * Lists all Product models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $searchModel = new ProductSearchFront();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $category = Category::find()->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'category'=>$category
        ]);
    }
```

Код Search Модели:

```php
class ProductSearchFront extends Product
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'cat_id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'img', 'url', 'maker', 'cat_name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function search($params){
        $query = Product::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'cat_id' => $this->cat_id,
//            'cat_name'=>$cat_name
        ]);


        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'img', $this->img])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'url', $this->url])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'maker', $this->maker])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'cat_name', $this->cat_name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Код вьюшки:

```php
<?
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
?>
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'emptyText'=>'Ничего не найдено',
    'options' => [
        'class'=>'list'
    ],
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return Html::a(Html::encode($model->name), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    },

]) ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Код вьюшки главной страницы:

```php
 <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($category as $cat):?>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h2><?= $cat->cat_name?></h2>
<!--                    --><?//= Html::a('Подробнее',['catalog/index', 'cat_name'=>$cat->cat_name, 'category'=>$category])?>
                    <?= Html::a('Подробнее',['catalog/index'])?> 
                </div>

            <?php endforeach;?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае, лучший способ - передавать `id` категории GET параметром и в контроллере фильтровать.

В search model должно быть что-то наподобие такого:

```
public function searchByCategory($params)
{
    $query = Product::find()->where(['cat_id'=>$params['cat_id']]);
    // Далее обработка фильтров и пр., как обычно.        
}
```

В контроллере:

```
public function actionByCategory($cat_id)
{        
    $searchModel = new ProductSearchFront();
    // Здесь отбор по id категории
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchByCategory(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $category = Category::find()->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'category'=>$category
    ]);
}
```

Примерно, как-то так...

P.S. Код писал прямо на сайте, просто чтобы показать принцип решения задачи. За работоспособность не ручаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо, я делал подобное, но не правильно использовал